# Malformed ObjectID: invalid character "u was found at index 0

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, stripe-payments, prisma

I am building an app using React, TS, MongoDB, Prisma and Stripe. While implementing Stripe subscription, I have this `Malformed ObjectID: invalid character 'u' was found at index 0 in the provided hex string: "user_2dXRtVzCiy9TT3yNgSz8EY7XdVQ".` error.

How can I fix this problem ?

My prisma.schema file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}



model UserApiLimit {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId String @unique
  count Int @default(0)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model UserSubscription {
  id String @id @db.ObjectId @map("_id") 
  userId String @unique
  stripeCustomerId String? @unique @map(name: "stripe_customer_id")
  stripeSubscriptionId String? @unique @map(name: "stripe_subscription_id")
  stripePriceId String? @map(name: "stripe_price_id")
  stripeCurrentPeriodEnd DateTime? @map(name: "current_period_end")
}
```

I had no problems with the id on UserApiLimit and tried to changed the id on subscription to `id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId` but it didn't work

Comment: Can you clarify which ID (of the five you have above) is returning that error, as well as which table it's in? What exactly are you trying to implement when this error is returned?

Comment: Try remove `id String @id @db.ObjectId @map("_id")` from block `model UserSubscription`

Comment: [ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) has its specific specification in MongoDB, which takes hexadecimal value. You may either make sure the value you supplied consists only of hexadecimal characters or make the field a pure string field